# Is there a special meaning of "\h"?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

Does \h have some special meaning? I store the username in a hidden field in my HTML, and all usernames works, but mine (which is DOMAIN\hers....) fails, it ends up like "DOMAINhers...) when picked up by Javascript (JQuery).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When storing strings in JavaScript you should always escape the `\` character, by replacing `\` with `\\`. Just imagine when someone has the username `DOMAIN\noel`. That will end up like

```
DOMAIN
oel
```

Answer (score 0):

\h isn't an escape character in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special meaning for "\h", but the backslash will still be escaped. You'll have to escape the backslash itself for your username to work so that you have "DOMAIN\hers....".